# How to clear cache in ionic v3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to know how to clear the ion cache for the ios platform when switching between tabs. I mean free memory, such as stored canvas, images, etc.

I mean inside the application. My application increases memory usage by rendering the canvas and it is not cleaned, it is maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a npm package available for this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache

This is an example code how to do it:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
        var success = function(status) {
            alert('Message: ' + status);
        }

        var error = function(status) {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }

        window.cache.clear( success, error );
        window.cache.cleartemp(); // 
}
```

Comment: Property 'cache' does not exist on type 'Window'. Did you mean 'caches'?ts(2551)
lib.dom.d.ts(17130, 14): 'caches' is declared here. I have this problem

Comment: Did you use `npm install`

Comment: Same error i am getting cache property not exists. in window